# How does hardware and compiler deal with an x86 instruction that crosses into a non-executable page?

Tags: memory, compiler-construction, assembly, x86

Unlike (most) RISC arch, x86 instructions have variable length. The start/end of an instruction doesn't have to aligned. If the compiler doesn't one instruction could be just lying across the page margin.

Assume that if the first byte of an instruction is at the last byte of a page, which is marked as executable. The rest bytes of the instruction are at the second page, which is marked as non-executable.

In such case, what will happen in the CPU when the execution reaches this instruction?

Does compiler need to care such cases?

Comment: Upvoted unexplained downvote.

Comment: When the next page *is* executable, it just works.  Fetch is done in aligned chunks, feeding a queue for the decoders.  Combining bytes from separate pages happens some time after fetch, after TLB checking, so it's not like a page-split data load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardware will (should, haven't tested) generate a GPF.

Compiler shouldn't care.

Comment: I seem to recall a bug relating to that with early iapx286 chips in protected mode.  Either it would fail to GPF on an instruction going over a boundary, or would erroneously GPF on an instruction that should just fit inside.  Can't recall at the moment...  #trivia  :-)